# I am getting an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to run KMedoids cluster analysis and plot a inertia vs number of cluster graph to find the ideal number of clusters using the elbow method. This is the code:

```
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids              
clusters = []
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids              
      2 clusters = []
      4 for i in range(1,11):

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sklearn_extra/cluster/__init__.py:2
      1 from ._k_medoids import KMedoids, CLARA
----> 2 from ._commonnn import commonnn, CommonNNClustering
      4 __all__ = ["KMedoids", "CLARA", "CommonNNClustering", "commonnn"]

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sklearn_extra/cluster/_commonnn.py:9
      2 """Density-Based Common-Nearest-Neighbors Clustering
      3 """
      5 # Author: Jan-Oliver Joswig <jan.joswig@fu-berlin.de>
      6 #
      7 # License: BSD 3 clause
----> 9 from distutils.version import LooseVersion
     10 import warnings
     12 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

I have python 3.12 installed and using jupyter notebook **without** anaconda navigator

Comment: Seems scikit-learn-extras does not support python 3.12, as distutils was removed in this latest version of python, so a solution is to downgrade python to a supported version.

Comment: I will go back to python 3.10 and try again,. Thank you professor